# Postgresql how do i find a table based on column name?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that I have a table with the column "fortyid" but I cant remember which table it is and I have like 350 tables in my database.
Is there a way to find all tables that has "fortyid" as column? (doesn't matter the type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [metadata defined by the SQL standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema), specifically [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html).

```
select c.*
from information_schema.columns c
where c.column_name = 'fortyid';
```